# CPU Scheduling Program Java Error (STCF/SRTF)

Tags: java, cpu

**I've looked at the other CPU scheduling programs on here but none seem to look like the one I'm working with right now.**

I was given a CPU scheduling program and told to write an "if statement" for the Shortest Time to Completion First (STCF or SRTF). There are 3 different files to the program.

Code is right below but I've also included a link to the Pastebin .java files are in the comments if you prefer that. Wasn't allowed to include the link up here.

This is "*Process.java*"

```
/**
 * Process class
 *
 * This class represents a process on our hypothetical system. Any information
 * about a single process should be stored here.
 * 
 *
 */

public class Process 
{
    // The name of the process. Can be set to something, but the current
    // program assigns arbitrary names.
    private String name;

    // The starting time of the process - the time that the process arrives
    // at the system to be run.
    private int startTime;

    // The ending time of the process - the time that the process completed
    // running on the system.
    private int endTime;

    // The first run time of the process - the time that the process was
    // first places on the CPU to be run.
    private int firstRunTime;

    // The amount of time left to complete the process - how much time until
    // the process finished.
    private int timeLeft;

    // The length of the process - how much time the process originally 
    // required to complete.
    private int length;

    // A boolean indicating in the process is finished or not.
    private boolean finished;


    /**
     * The constructor for the Process class.
     * 
     * @param n The name of the process.
     * @param s The start time of the process.
     * @param len The length of the process.
     */

    public Process( String n, int s, int len )
    {
        name = n;
        startTime = s;
        endTime = -1;       // End time is calculated while running.
        firstRunTime = -1;  // First run time is calculated while running.
        timeLeft = len;     // Initial time left is length of process.
        length = len;
        finished = false;
    }


    /**
     * This method is called when the time on the system advances one step.
     * It should only be called on a process that is currently running on
     * the CPU.
     * 
     * @param time The current time in the system
     */
    public void tick( int time )
    {
        // One second of running has occurred, so less time is left.
        timeLeft--;

        // If there is no time left on the process, then the process
        // is finished, and the end time is the current time.
        if ( timeLeft == 0 )
        {
            finished = true;
            endTime = time;
        }
    }


    // Sets the firstRunTime to the time passed as the parameter.
    public void startRunning( int time )
    {
        // Only change it if it has not been changed before.
        if ( firstRunTime == - 1 )
            firstRunTime = time;
    }


    // Return the name of the process.
    public String getName( )
    {
        return name;
    }


    // Return the time left of the process.
    public int getTimeLeft( )
    {
        return timeLeft;
    }


    // Returns whether or not the process is finished.
    public boolean isFinished( )
    {
        return finished;
    }


    // Returns the starting time of the process.
    public int getStartTime( )
    {
        return startTime;
    }


    // Returns the end time of the process.
    public int getEndTime( )
    {
        return endTime;
    }


    // Returns the first time that the process started running.
    public int getFirstRunTime( )
    {
        return firstRunTime;
    }


    // Returns the original length of the process.
    public int getLength( )
    {
        return length;
    }
}
```

This is "*CPU.java*" The only method I personally added is "*public int remainingTime()*"

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * The CPU class.
 * This class represents a CPU that is running on our system.
 * 
 *
 */
public class CPU 
{
    // This process is the process that is currently running on the CPU.
    private Process running;

    // This variable is true if the CPU is empty (not running a process).
    private boolean empty;

    // This variable stores the names of the processes that were run on
    // the CPU over the course of the simulation.
    private ArrayList<String> chart;


    /**
     * The constructor for the CPU class. We assume that the CPU is not
     * running anything initially.
     */

    public CPU( )
    {
        running = null;
        empty = true;
        chart = new ArrayList<String>( );
    }


    /**
     * This method is used to start a process running on the CPU. The process
     * to start is called p, and the time it is started is time.
     * 
     * @param p  The process to start running on the system.
     * @param time  The current time.
     */

    public void begin( Process p, int time )
    {
        // If the process p is null, then don't do anything.
        if ( p != null )
        {
            // If the CPU is empty and there is time left to run on process p,
            // then start p running.
            if ( empty && ( p.getTimeLeft( ) > 0 ) )
            {
                running = p;
                running.startRunning( time );
                empty = false;
            }
            // Otherwise, print an appropriate error message.
            else if ( !empty )
            {
                System.out.println( "CPU is currently running another process." );
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println( "Process is already finished." );
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * The tick method advances the CPU one time tick. If the process that is
     * currently running on the CPU finishes, it is returned from the method;
     * otherwise it will return null.
     * 
     * @param time
     * @return The process that completed; null if no process completed
     */
    public Process tick( int time )
    {
        // **Basically: return either process or nothing (if a process is running). Nothing on CPU, return NULL.
        // If the CPU is currently running something, do this stuff.
        if ( !empty )
        {
            // Advance the process running on the CPU one time tick.
            running.tick( time );

            // Add the name of the process running to the chart.
            chart.add( running.getName( ) );

            // If the process is finished now, remove it from the CPU and
            // return it.
            if ( running.isFinished( ) )
            {
                empty = true;
                return running;
            }
            // If the process is not finished, return null.
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        // If the CPU is not running anything, it is empty, so add
        // null to the chart, then return null.
        chart.add( null );
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * Return the value of the empty variable.
     * @return Whether or not the CPU is empty.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty( )
    {
        return empty;
    }

    public int remainingTime()
    {
        return running.getTimeLeft();
    }


    /**
     * This method prints the CPU usage chart, 20 time ticks per line. This
     * code assumes the names of the processes are two characters - if they
     * are not, the chart will not line up well.
     */
    public void printChart( )
    {
        int i = 1;

        for ( String s : chart )
        {
            // If no process was running, this will print XX on the chart.
            if ( s != null )
                System.out.print( s + " " );
            else
                System.out.print( "XX " );

            // After 20 items, move to the next line.
            if ( ( i % 20 ) == 0 )
                System.out.println( );

            i++;
        }
        System.out.println( );
    }
}
```

And this is "*Simulator.java*", where STCF is supposed to go.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * The Simulator class, which executes the simulation.
 * 
 *
 */

public class Simulator 
{
    // cpu1 is the CPU of the system.
    private CPU cpu1;

    // ready stores the processes that are ready to run and are waiting for
    // the CPU.
    private ArrayList<Process> ready;

    // finished stores the processes that have finished execution.
    private ArrayList<Process> finished;

    // time stores the current time of the system.
    private int time;

    // END_TIME indicates how long the simulation will run.
    private final int END_TIME = 250;

    // PROC_ARRIVE_PERCENT indicates the percent chance that a new process
    // will arrive to run on the CPU at any given time unit.
    private final int PROC_ARRIVE_PERCENT = 80;

    // PROC_MIN_LENGTH is the minimum length that a process can be.
    private final int PROC_MIN_LENGTH = 5;

    // PROC_MAX_LENGTH is the maximum length that a process can be.
    private final int PROC_MAX_LENGTH = 15;

    // SCHEDULING_ALGORITHM indicates which algorithm the simulation
    // will be using. Options are "FIFO", "SJF", "STCF", "RR", and
    // "MLFQ".
    private final String SCHEDULING_ALGORITHM = "STCF";

    /**
     * The constructor for the Simulator class. Everything starts as
     * a new Object, and time starts at 0.
     */
    public Simulator( )
    {
        cpu1 = new CPU( );
        ready = new ArrayList<Process>( ); // processes ready to go
        finished = new ArrayList<Process>( ); // once processes are finished, they go here
        time = 0;
    }

    /**
     * The main function runs the program. This just creates a Simulator
     * Object, and calls its run method.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // create simulator then run
        Simulator s = new Simulator( );

        s.run( );
    }

    /**
     * The addProcess starts a new process at the current time.
     * @param name - The name of the process to add.
     * @param start - The start time for the process to add.
     * @param length - The length of the process to add.
     */
    public void addProcess( String name, int start, int length )
    {
        // take stuff, creates new process, add to ArrayList
        Process temp = new Process( name, start, length );
        ready.add( temp );
    }


    /**
     * Select the next process to run on the CPU. The algorithm is determined
     * by the value of the SCHEDULING_ALGORITHM variable.
     * @param ready  The set of processes that are ready to run.
     * @return  Returns the process selected to run.
     */
    public Process select( ArrayList<Process> ready )
    {
        // TO-DO
        // **This is the part I'm working on**
        if (SCHEDULING_ALGORITHM.equals("STCF"))
        {
            int i = 0;
            int shortestTime = 0;
            int startTime = 0;
            int timeLeft = 0;

            Process proc = new Process(SCHEDULING_ALGORITHM, startTime, timeLeft);
            CPU cpu = new CPU();
            timeLeft = proc.getTimeLeft();

            if (ready.isEmpty() == false)
            {
                    // check the ready ArrayList for the next job with the shortest time left
                    // if the current process has the shortest time, it will automatically be selected again.
                while (i <= ready.size())
                {
                    if (proc.getTimeLeft() < cpu.remainingTime())
                    {
                        shortestTime = proc.getTimeLeft();
                    }
                    i++;
                }

                i = 0;

                while (i <= ready.size())
                {
                    if (proc.getTimeLeft() == shortestTime)
                    {
                        // remove running process from CPU. Store for later.

                        ready.remove(i);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    /*
     * remove first process from ready ArrayList
     * run that process
     * while running that process, check the ready ArrayList.
     * if a process in the ready ArrayList is smaller than the remaining time of the one running,
     * remove that process from the CPU. Save the remaining time left of that job.
     * Put the new job on.
     * When remaining time left on a job is 0, move to finished ArrayList.
     */


    // run the first process for 2 seconds first

    // Check ready ArrayList for shortest process.
    // If shortest process is still the current array, run for 2 more seconds.
    // Else if it is different, run that different process. Save spot of last process.

    /**
     * The run method runs the entire simulation. We assume that this 
     * method is run immediately after creating the Simulator object.
     */
    public void run( )
    {
        // Various variables needed.
        Process temp;
        Random r = new Random( ); // processes arriving randomly
        int procTime;
        char ch1 = 'A', ch2 = 'A';
        char[] n;
        String s;

        System.out.println( "Beginning simulation." );

        // Loop until the time gets to the end.
        while ( time < END_TIME )
        {
            // See if a new process arrives.
            if ( r.nextInt( 100 ) < PROC_ARRIVE_PERCENT )
            {
                System.out.println( "New process arrived at time = " + time );
                // Create a new name by incrementing the characters.
                n = new char[2];
                n[0] = ch1;
                n[1] = ch2;
                s = new String( n );
                if ( ch2 == 'Z' )
                {
                    ch1++;
                    ch2 = 'A';
                }
                else
                {
                    ch2++;
                }

                // Creates a process with a random length between the minimum and maximum lengths.
                procTime = r.nextInt( PROC_MAX_LENGTH - PROC_MIN_LENGTH + 1 ) + PROC_MIN_LENGTH;
                addProcess( s, time, procTime );
            }

            // Increment the time on the CPU.
            temp = cpu1.tick( time );

            // If a job finished, add it to finished.
            if ( temp != null )
            {
                finished.add( temp );
            }

            // If there is nothing on the CPU, add something to it.
            if ( cpu1.isEmpty( ) )
            {
                temp = select( ready );
                cpu1.begin( temp, time );
            }

            time++;
        }

        // Print the results.
        printResults( ready, finished );
    }


    /**
     * This method prints the results of the simulation.
     * @param ready - the list of jobs waiting for the CPU.
     * @param finished - the list of jobs that finished during the simulation.
     */
    public void printResults( ArrayList<Process> ready, ArrayList<Process> finished )
    {
        // Variables to calculate results.
        int totalResponseTime = 0;
        int totalTurnaroundTime = 0;
        double avgRT, avgTT;

        int s, f, fr, r, t, l;
        String n;

        // Everything on ready is unfinished. Ignore the job currently running on the CPU.
        System.out.println( "There are " + ready.size() + " unfinished processes." );
        System.out.println( );

        // Print results from all finished processes.
        System.out.println( "Name   Arrive   First Run   Finished   Length   Response   Turnaround" );
        for ( Process p : finished )
        {
            n = p.getName( );
            s = p.getStartTime( );
            f = p.getEndTime( );
            fr = p.getFirstRunTime( );
            l = p.getLength( );
            r = fr - s;
            t = f - s;

            System.out.format( "%4s   %6d   %9d   %8d   %6d   %8d   %10d%n", n, s, fr, f, l, r, t );

            totalResponseTime += r;
            totalTurnaroundTime += t;
        }

        // Calculate average response and turnaround times.
        avgRT = (double)totalResponseTime / finished.size( );
        avgTT = (double)totalTurnaroundTime / finished.size( );

        System.out.println( );
        System.out.format( "Averages                                        %8.2f   %10.2f%n", avgRT, avgTT );

        // Print out the CPU usage chart.
        System.out.println( );
        cpu1.printChart( );
    }
}
```

This is what I have for STCF so far, but I keep getting errors, in this case:

```
Beginning simulation.
New process arrived at time = 0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at CPU.remainingTime(CPU.java:118)
    at Simulator.select(Simulator.java:153)
    at Simulator.run(Simulator.java:246)
    at Simulator.main(Simulator.java:64)
```

It's supposed to look something like this for FIFO when the chance of a process arriving is change to 20%, minimum length of a process is 2, max length of a process is 5 and End Time is 100:
[FIFO Results (Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNROi.png)

I was just wondering if my STCF/SRTF code was producing those errors. Been trying to figure this out for hours but have had no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Here are the PasteBin files. They download as ".java" files.

Process.java - http://pastebin.com/qGGR3GUG

CPU.java - http://pastebin.com/VtqgLhcr

Simulator.java - http://pastebin.com/cAHdH4V8

Comment: Why don’t you just look at the stack trace which already provides you with everything you need? It tells you that the NPE occurred at line 118 in `CPU.java` within method `remainingTime`, so it’s obvious that `running` is `null` and that shouldn’t surprise you when you consider that the only place where a non-`null` value is ever assigned to `running` is the method `begin` which you call *after* `select` (when `select` didn’t fail with an NPE).